# Which is better pure **OpenLayers** or **GeoExt**?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

Which is better pure **OpenLayers** or **GeoExt**?

Which has more options with respect to GIS client-side

Comment: @JanJee.. Please explain your question in detail..thanks

Comment: It all depends on what features you require in your web app. If you want just a map, then Openlayers will be fine. Please provide more details, so that we can answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat of a trick question.  In terms of *GIS functionality*, both GeoExt and OpenLayers are very good, approximately equally well-suited to whatever your application is.  This is because **GeoExt is based on OpenLayers**.

The real question you should be asking is whether you're already working in an environment with a powerful Javascript DOM-manipulation library like jQuery, mooTools, or Prototype.  If so, then you should avoid GeoExt (mixing DOM Libraries makes very muddy code) and choose OpenLayers.  One caveat here is that if you're already working with Ext.js and you're not relying upon bleeding-edge functionality, you should be able to just drop-in GeoExt without much difficulty.  If you're starting from scratch, on the other hand, then it really doesn't matter which one you choose--pick the DOM manipulator you like better: if it's Ext, use GeoExt.  If not, use OpenLayers.